# Can I do server to server authentication on AWS Cognito using something like OAuth2 service accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I have a file server that is set up with a Cognito user pool and app client so users can login using basic authentication and the OAuth2.0 authorization code flow.

I need external apps to be able to **authenticate themselves without user input**, and **be able to impersonate an actual user**.

OAuth2.0 has service accounts, which sounds like what I need, but does Cognito have something similar that I could use? Or is it possible to work in the OAuth2.0 service accounts into what I have working in Cognito?

I know OAuth has the client credentials flow which Cognito provides as an option, but I'm confused on the use case for this/how it would work. I'm guessing the external apps would each be their own app client (with their own client ID, client secret) for the user pool, and they'd use their own credentials to authenticate themselves before grabbing files? And how would impersonating a user be done?

Thanks for your help.